# How to mock results of Enumerable.Any() extension using moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm using mongo driver, and trying to fake results of any to test whether Insert or Update was called based on results.

Here's piece of code I think relevant:

```
_context = _collection.AsQueryable();
if (_context.Any(s => s.Id == id))
{
...
```

after that I'm calling either `_collection.Update()` or `_collection.Insert()`.

Here's what I tried so far with the unit test:

```
var collectionMock = new Mock<MongoCollection<Storage>>();
var queriableMock = new Mock<IQueryable<Storage>>();
queriableMock.Setup(q => Enumerable.Any(q)).Returns(() => false);

...
collectionMock.Setup(c => c.AsQueryable()).Returns(() => queriableMock.Object);
collectionMock.Setup(c => c.Save(It.IsAny<Storage>()));
```

I'm getting exception

> "Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked
>   object: q => q.Any()"

Comment: It seems like you're trying to mock the static `Enumerable.Any()` method which is not possible.  Why would you need to mock that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Setup` method takes a lambda that is not *executed* but is *interpreted* so that the mock can identify methods/properties of the mock object that will be called during the test and what should be returned/thrown/called back/etc.

Moq doesn't know the implementation of `Enumerable.Any<T>(this T item)`, and therefore cannot figure out what methods or properties of `T` will be accessed or what they should do/return.

Therefore, in order to mock a call to `Enumerable.Any`, you need to identify what methods/properties of your object it, in turn, calls, and then mock those.

[You can find the implementation here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#577032c8811e20d3).  Simply follow the call path and mock out everything `Any` needs to call.

Comment: That didn't help me much since _collection.AsQueriable() was also static and I'd need to mock that too. At the end I solved this by changing the original code not to use Linq at all, and I found my records using FindOne() method which was simple to mock. But thanks for the idea, I'll accept your answer since noone else bothered to help :)